# Why do level curves of a function and its harmonic conjugate intersect each other orthogonally?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, orthogonality

So I've had this assignment in which I had to proof that two level curves of a function and one of its harmonic conjugates intersect each other orthogonally.

The proof itself wasn't that difficult, but I wondered: why does this happen?

What is the underlying cause for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of the Cauchy-Riemann equations:
$$
u_x=v_y,\\u_y=-v_x,
$$
which imply that
$$
\nabla u \,\perp\, \nabla v.
$$